# Visual Studio 2003 - Corruption in project - Not displaying project properties

Tags: visual-studio-2003

I am using Visual Studio 2003 and I having a strange problem. I have a solution file in which several projects are added. However, due to some corruption, i cannot see the properties of one project. It gives a message box saying "unspecified error" when i try to check the properties of that project. The delete option of the project is also disabled. Can anyone knows what exactly went wrong ? Any help will be highly appreciated.